# Multiple kendo grid from single datasource

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I have 4 kendo grids in four tabs of a single tabstrip. The requirement is to populate them based on a single textbox input. How do I populate all four of them from a single datasource?

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datasource/shared-datasource

Comment: Hi, I need to select depending on a where condition. I mean, my sp will return the whole tablevariable but the data needs to be shown in different grids based on a condition of a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a datasource which will get data.
Foreach grid have a different datasource.
In the grids datasource initialization do something like:

```
   dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: globalDataSource.data() }),
```

Then you can apply filters foreach grid's datasource inidividually, like:

```
filter: { field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane" }
```

Or you can set each grid datasource based on condition:

```
if (condition){
      $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(globalDataSource);
}
else{
      $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({data: [] }););
}
```

Comment: so i can put in like filter:{field : RISK , operator:"equals",value:"High"}, this populates only those records in my grid with high values in the datasource. similary other grids. Help me if I am wrong please.

Comment: Hi, I am using the post method to post the data in the controller from my Index VIEW, executing the sp there and now my sp has returned the list in the Post actionresult method. Now how do i read this list from my partial view action results/ how do i filter this whole chunk into my partial views?